# How can i calculate the days difference between two distinct status transitions for the same id using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Fo first things first, i'll just start with a sample data based on which I will explain my desired outcome:

| Index | ID | timestamp | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25730 | 2020-06-24 07:22:31.297 | In Progress |
| 2 | 25730 | 2020-06-29 06:28:20.193 | Ready |
| 3 | 25730 | 2020-06-30 07:21:05.147 | In Progress |
| 4 | 25730 | 2020-06-30 09:40:27.670 | Ready |
| 5 | 25730 | 2020-07-01 07:23:11.277 | In Progress |
| 6 | 25730 | 2020-07-05 11:06:02.413 | Ready |
| 110 | 25735 | 2020-06-30 09:36:04.050 | Ready |
| 141 | 25738 | 2020-06-28 11:49:09.557 | In Progress |
| 142 | 25738 | 2020-06-28 11:51:44.503 | Ready |
| 143 | 25738 | 2020-06-29 05:05:45.777 | In Progress |
| 144 | 25738 | 2020-06-29 05:12:54.617 | Ready |
| 145 | 25738 | 2020-07-13 12:17:46.873 | Ready |
| 146 | 25738 | 2020-07-15 16:21:09.667 | In Progress |
| 147 | 25738 | 2020-07-20 16:46:59.840 | Ready |
| 148 | 25738 | 2020-07-24 16:49:57.003 | In Progress |

Based on the above mentioned example, I'm trying to calculate the days difference between status transitions. More specifically how long it took for an id to make the transition from "**Ready**"
to "**In Progress**" (this transition can apply multiple times for the same id). The other transitions are not important.
Below is an example of my desired outcome along with what I have tried so far:

```
Diff = 
     var _ready = calculate(FIRSTNONBLANK(Query1[timestamp_utc],filter(query1,Query1[nextstatus] = "Ready")))
     var _progress = calculate(FIRSTNONBLANK(Query1[timestamp_utc],filter(Query1,Query1[nextstatus]="In Progress")))
    return
    DATEDIFF(_ready,_progress,day)
```

| index | id | timestamp | status | Days diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25730 | 2020-06-24 07:22:31.297 | In Progress |  |
| 2 | 25730 | 2020-06-29 06:28:20.193 | Ready |  |
| 3 | 25730 | 2020-06-30 07:21:05.147 | In Progress | 1 |
| 4 | 25730 | 2020-06-30 09:40:27.670 | Ready |  |
| 5 | 25730 | 2020-07-01 07:23:11.277 | In Progress | 1 |
| 6 | 25730 | 2020-07-05 11:06:02.413 | Ready |  |
| 110 | 25735 | 2020-06-30 09:36:04.050 | Ready |  |
| 141 | 25738 | 2020-06-28 11:49:09.557 | In Progress |  |
| 142 | 25738 | 2020-06-28 11:51:44.503 | Ready |  |
| 143 | 25738 | 2020-06-29 05:05:45.777 | In Progress | 1 |
| 144 | 25738 | 2020-06-29 05:12:54.617 | Ready |  |
| 145 | 25738 | 2020-07-13 12:17:46.873 | Ready |  |
| 146 | 25738 | 2020-07-15 16:21:09.667 | In Progress | 2 |
| 147 | 25738 | 2020-07-20 16:46:59.840 | Ready |  |
| 148 | 25738 | 2020-07-24 16:49:57.003 | In Progress | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole measure (If index is unique):

```
Measure 2 = 
var __currentIndex = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Index])
var __currentID = SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[ID])
var __previousReady = CALCULATE( MAX(Sheet1[timestamp]), FILTER(ALL(Sheet1), Sheet1[ID] = __currentID && Sheet1[Index] < __currentIndex && Sheet1[Status] = "Ready"))

return
CALCULATE( DATEDIFF(__previousReady, SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[timestamp]) ,DAY), FILTER(ALL(Sheet1[Status]), Sheet1[Status] = "In Progress"))
```

[image]